How can I activate PhpStorm? I have 6 month free activation key
My PhpStorm notifications say trial period end in a few days. But I activated 6 month period with a key on JetBrains website.
Tried to find in PhpStorm app account settings. But I cannot find the place where I can link my account that I entered on JetBrains website.

Product support questions should go to JetBrains, not Stack Overflow.

Make sure you're logged in with the same account you added the trail key to.

It should be in the navigation header menu.
Help -> Register

For your case select the JetBrains Account option
